# How to stop more than one being removed from an integer?

Tags: c++

I know the title may seem fairly confusing, was just unsure on how to ask this...
So, I'm working on a basic sample game (not going to be a complete game or anything), where you can move around and are chased by an enemy character that attacks you. The problem is that when the attack function is called, instead of only removing one heart/hitpoint, they continue to be 'spam removed'. Here's what I'm working with...

```
void Enemy::attackPlayer()
{
    if (distance < 50)
    {
        Player::health--;
        return;
    }
}
```

Pretty simple, right? Well the problem is that I need some way of I guess 'sleeping' the single function so that instead of continuing to remove health, it stops after one, then after let's say, 3 seconds, allows another attack to occur.

Comment: You can use Sleep(3000); by #include<windows.h>

Comment: Take a time stamp every successful attack, and then don't allow another attack until 3 seconds after that timestamp. For taking time stamps look at `std::chrono`

Comment: Have tried that Mohammed, however that isn't isolated to the function, it freezes the entire program.

Comment: Essentially, it is a better solution to ensure this kind of thing in your event handler.

Comment: You should not actually freeze, for example using `Sleep`.

Comment: Is Player::health referring to a static class variable?  If so you might want to consider instances of Enemy and Player instead of class variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking some of the answers you guys gave me into consideration and messing around with some things by myself, I've came up with a pretty simple solution:

```
int Enemy::attackTime = 0;
```

And then...

```
void Enemy::attackPlayer()
{
    if (distance > 60)
        return;

    if (time(0) > attackTime)
    {
        attackTime = time(0) + 3;
        Player::health--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create two global time variables that are passed to your attack function. startTime is initiated once you call your attack function (outside). endTime is initiated right after removing one health from player (inside your function). Then you simply add a if statement before the distance if statement to check the delta time between these two and if they are more than 3 seconds then do the rest to remove another health.

Comment: Actually, I think this sounds a bit better and easier than what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably have the `Enemy` class contain a method like:

```
bool canAttack(){
    if(attackTimer >= 3000){
        attackTimer = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you could modify your damage condition to be something like:

```
if (distance < 50 && canAttack())
```

Of course, you would have to add a timer to the `Enemy` class and have it start and stop based on proximity to the player.

I'm sure there is a better way to handle this--also, this depends a bit on the implementation of the rest of your code.  If you are using something like SFML, there is a built-in event system that would make this a bit easier to handle.  Hopefully this helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, player won't get another attacked from any enemy for 3 seconds. However, enemy can attack to another player if exist. Thus, this timer variable is keep into Player class. If I am correct, I think this code will work.

```
class Player
{
private:
    uint32_t last_attack_timer;
    ...
public:
    void set_last_attack_timer(uint32_t timer){this->last_attack_timer = timer;};
    uint32_t get_last_attack_timer(void){return last_attack_timer;};
    ...
}

void Enemy::attackPlayer()
{
    uint32_t timer = time(0);

    if (distance < 50 && timer-Player::get_last_attack_timer>3000)
    {
        Player::health--;
        Player::set_last_attack_timer(timer(0));
        return;
    }
}
```